# Variable with vacant value

Tags: r, variables

I want to know how **R** treats the vacant value of a variable. I mean: I have a variable with two values: 1 (a behavior occurs) 0 (a behavior doesn't occur). But in my table same data are missing because I couldn't see the behavior, so there are some vacant. if I work with this variable, I can use it without any problems or, before working, I have to get out the vacant data and remain just only with the known variables?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do with the data. In R you would usually use `NA` for missing data. Some functions can deal with this, for example:

```
mean(c(1, NA))
# [1] NA
mean(c(1, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 1
```

but in other cases you may need to eliminate missing values before performing analysis, for example using the `subset` function.